# Div reading as null still

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

The second part of this is reading null for some reason. It's working for the first part.

```
window.onload = function() {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.className = "jack";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

second part

```
document.onmousemove=function(e){
  var x, y;
  if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} 
  else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;}
  var jack = document.getElementById('jack');
  jack.style.top=y+'px';
  jack.style.left=x+50+'px';
}};
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.className = "jack";
document.body.appendChild(div);

document.onmousemove=function(e){
  var x, y;
  if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} 
  else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;}
  var jack = document.getElementByClassName('jack');
  jack.style.top=y+'px';
  jack.style.left=x+50+'px';
  }};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What precisely is the second part? What's your html? Provice better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targetting `#jack` but that element doesn't have an id, only a class. Add the following to the part of the code where you're creating the element.

```
div.id = "jack";
```

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.id = "jack";
document.body.appendChild(div);

document.onmousemove=function(e){
  var x, y;
  if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} 
  else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;}
  var jack = document.getElementById('jack');
  jack.style.top=y+'px';
  jack.style.left=x+50+'px';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

same story:
getElement**s**ByClassName() returns HTMLCollection (array of HTMLElements), getElement**s**ByClassName("css-class")[0] is the first HTMLElement found.

the only exception is getElementById() method. it returns single HTMLElement (because id attribute is unique - one document cannot contain two elements with same id values)